# Are there any (liquid) chemicals that experience rapid, extensive, and controllable volume changes in reaction to heat?

Tags: thermodynamics

The larger purpose of this question is the engineering of liquid filled sacs that change their volume according to heat. They'd need to have diverse ranges of volume, at least a factor of ten (a 10 ml to 100ml transition).

Comment: I don't think you will find any liquids that will fit your requirements. After all, thermometers would tend to use liquids with large thermo expansion coefficients. The liquids in the thermometers don't even double in volume. Mercury has a volume coefficient of $182\times 10^{-6}K^{-1}$, so a temperature change of $10000K$ is needed to double the volume.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29700/what-reactions-create-a-lot-of-gas-really-quickly - you'd need to produce gas